# Print a string and then print the string next to the next sting in python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

Sorry for my English, Is there any way to print a list like this,

```
list = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

to

```
list_1 = ["a","c","e"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you mean to convert *list* to *list_1*. We can do it through *slicing*.

```
list = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
list_1 = list[::2]
print(list_1)
```